# Galois connection, basic property, inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, galois-connections

Let $A,B$ be sets and $\mu:{\cal P}(A)\to {\cal P}(B),$and $\iota:{\cal P}(B)
\to {\cal P}(A),$where $\cal P$ denotes the power set.
Let $X,X'\subseteq A$ and $Y,Y'\subseteq B.$
Suppose that we have a Galois connection

(i) $X\subseteq X' \Rightarrow \mu(X)\supseteq \mu(X')$

(ii) $Y \subseteq Y' \Rightarrow \iota(Y)\supseteq \mu(Y')$

(iii) $X\subseteq\iota\mu(X)$

(iv) $Y\subseteq\mu\iota(Y)$

Let $T\subseteq A$.

Which inclusion holds in general:

$$\iota\mu(T)\subseteq\bigcup_{a\in T}\iota\mu(\{a\}),$$ or the reverse one:

$$\iota\mu(T)\supseteq\bigcup_{a\in T}\iota\mu(\{a\})$$

? Do (iii) and (iv) follow from (i) and (ii)? Why?

Comment: A couple questions: does $\iota\mu = \iota \circ\mu$, like composition? Also, do you mean $X \in \iota \mu(X)$, because you have a powerset of $A$, and $X \subset A \implies X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$

Comment: I do not know. I've just rewritten a paragraph from a book. I think $\iota\mu = \iota \circ\mu$

Comment: Type ("galois connection between A and B" powerset) into google and follow the link. Part of the book shows.

Comment: You should rewrite the exercise, I think you made a mistake in copying it. Indeed a Galois connection would be $\mu(X) \leq Y \iff X\leq \iota(Y)$. This yields $X\leq \iota\mu(Y)$, and $\mu\iota(Y) \leq Y$, not the other way around. $\iota\mu$ is increasing, and this should yield clearly which inclusion holds

Comment: You have some typo in your comment. Anyway, I do not understand how $X\leq\iota\mu(X)$ follow from the first two inequalities?

Comment: @Max There is nothing wrong with the definition. Indeed, there is the concept of [antitone Galois connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection#Antitone_Galois_connection). I even used to think there were only antitone ones...

Comment: @amrsa my bad, I tend to think of Galois connections purely as adjunctions between preorders as categories, so I only think of monotone ones.

Comment: @Max I'm aware that in some books, even in order theory, Galois connections are defined to be monotone. I think it's kind of two different worlds, and sometimes we need to make it clear what we're talking about. :)

Answer (score 0):

For $a \in T$, you have $\{a\} \subseteq T$, whence 
$$\mu(\{a\}) \supseteq \mu(T),$$
by (i) and 
$$\iota\mu(\{a\}) \subseteq \iota\mu(T),$$
by (ii), yielding 
$$\iota\mu(T) \supseteq \bigcup_{a \in T} \iota\mu(\{a\}).$$